# Is there a possibility to create non rounded corners with bevel tool or bevel modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

Is it possible to create sharp / pointing vertex with bevel tool or modifier the way it is shown on the right cube?

I am able only to create the type of bevels as on the left cube - to get the results of the right cube I had to select each edge separately and that is obviously not the most efficient way.

[image]

Comment: Currently no. But there are some ideas about it here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/gsoc-2018-bevel-improvements/440/274 and somewhere here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/gsoc-2019-custom-bevel-profiles/7214

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with modifiers, and it's only about one cube, then you could solve it completely with *Geometry Nodes*.

Just add a *Geometry Nodes* modifier, and use this node group:

[image]

This will simply create a cube. This has the size specified in the *Modifier Properties*.

Additionally there is the value *Amount*, which like the *Bevel Modifier* changes the size of the bevel.

Basically, I create a cube here, extrude the faces outward, and scale them to create a beveled edge with a $45°$ angle.

Finally, the cube is simply scaled back to the original size, and you have the desired result. 100% procedural.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Neat... a leftover from struggles with a _Bevel_ group? :)

Comment: @RobinBetts No, not quite, but it also reminded me of [this challenge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264169/) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of modifiers to accomplish a similar result as I demonstrate in this question: [Sverchok Decimate and Weld](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/266859/61334)