# How to move edge loops with geometry nodes

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am fairly new to blender and I am starting to use the geometry nodes. Currently I am asking myself if there is a way to subdivide the surface of a cube unevenly. What I mean by that is more easily explained in this image then explaining it by text: [image]

I believe this has to be done with moving the centerpoint of every face in two steps:

1. move center point of all faces in a row
2. move center point of all faces in a collum
3. subdivide

This way I would keep the structure that I want in the xy-plane and not have randomly displaced n-gons.
Is this possible by using geometry nodes?

Comment: It looks like you want to move edge loops is this what you want?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUAXKcfvx7A

Comment: @RickT nice question, would be great to have an regular answer :) (or is it dupli here?) Thank you

Comment: @knoeterich ... consider to change title to something like RickT's "How to move edge loop" if you feel it right ... uneven subdivisions sounds more like random that is without specific control, and that is not your case.

Comment: @vklidu  I can't say if it's really a dup, the user hasn't responded to say if that's what they want or not.

Comment: What might be interesting here as well is: do you want this to be procedural, so that you can easily change parameters like number of cuts, which edges and how far they are moved etc.? If so the question would be in which way will all these things be determined? And if you don't need to keep this procedural the question would be, why do you want to do it in _Geometry Nodes_?

Comment: @RickT Yea! The youtube link you attached is what I was looking for :) Thx!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes I want to use this procedurally so I only have to adjust one value. I did not try this yes but I think with the method presented in the youTube-video it'll work :)

Comment: I think there isn't really a different answer than: use "Set Position" node… And Maths… https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/264240/60486