# Sverchok Decimate and Weld

Tags: bevel

in an attempt to answer this question: [Is there a possibility to create non rounded corners with bevel tool or bevel modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146711/is-there-a-possibility-to-create-non-rounded-corners-with-bevel-tool-or-bevel-mo)
I have achieved a special kind of bevel using a combination of modifiers in Blender's modifier stack. I am now wondering how to achieve this with Sverchok. The combination of modifiers has two bevel modifiers. One set to edges and the other set to vertices. After those two a combination of a decimate and a weld modifier are applied to achieve the desired result. The closest I found in Sverchok to the decimate and weld modifiers are the merge by distance. However that node doesn't seem to offer the some sort of control that the decimate and weld modifiers combo offers. Maybe there is a way to achieve the result using Sverchok's masks? Thanks for the help. P.S. I used a points inside mesh node to "select" which vertices to "collapse" with the first merge by distance node.

Solution with modifiers:[image: mods bevel]

Sverchok attempt:[image: sverchok bevels]

Comment: @evaru I was trying to answer your question but am blocked for some reason, don't know why; https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/77433/evaru

Comment: haha. nice challange, will try now

Answer (score 0):

First attempt. But works only for cube. Next step should be definition for individual vertex normal movement... most complicated part as i see.

this is gist for import:
https://gist.github.com/5a47a669d98aad3d3418490faca764a7

[image: bevel example screenshot]

Comment: Dude, man what kind of magic is it? Is it some kind of Python code. How to use that, how to create something the same? Can you at least give some link with information?

Comment: also look at https://gist.github.com/nortikin/53c9597a57d70a09e45197b424f1c00d